# Local Data Storage - Universal Windows APP

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uwp

I´m new to programming an UWA. My problem:
I want to program a little database to store different data. So I made a GUI with different `TextBoxes`. Now I want to store these data in a file. If you close the program and open it you should be possible to get the data.
How do i implement that?

Best Regards,
CD Rohling

Edit: Im programming in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two of (a lot more) possible ways here:

- using SQLLite
  https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Implement-SQLite-Local-8b13a307
- use JSON.NET (available as nuget package for uwp) serialize/deserialize and save it to isolated storage 
  http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeWithJsonSerializerToFile.htm
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf96a1wz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thank you for your fast response!!!!!